# Is the method beginIgnoringInteractionEvents supposed to disable non-touch events?

Tags: ios, uiapplication, svprogresshud

I have a text box that is used to look up from a large list of potential options via a web service and then list them in a table view.

On start/complete I call them

```
+ (void)showProgressHUDIfNecessary {
    if ([RestKitWebServiceRequest operationCount] == 0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
        [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
    }
}

+ (void)dismissProgressHUDIfNecessary {
    if ([RestKitWebServiceRequest operationCount] == 0) {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    }
}
```

While the indicator is spinning, touch events are most definitely disabled but when running from iPhone Simulator I can still input into the text box without restriction.

How can I ensure that *all* user input is disabled, including keyboard input as just described?

Comment: SVProgressHUD is itself disable all toches if mask type is set to gradient. If you still face the problem you can disable the user intersection on current key window.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos start a bounty, this is a serious issue, or a bug to be filed to Apple...